# No applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, r-sf, rpostgresql

I am trying to transfer data from the Thingspeak API into a postgres database. The API limits each request to 8000 observations, but I need to pull millions! I'm using R to iteratively pull from the API, do a bunch of wrangling, and then submit the results as a `data.frame` to my table within the db.

The current way I am doing this relies on the `dbWriteTable()` function from the `RPostgres` package. However, this method does not account for existing observations in the db. I have to manually `DELETE FROM table_name` before running the script or I'll end up writing duplicate observations each time I try to update the db. I'm still wasting time re-writing observations that I deleted, and the script takes ~2 days to complete because of this.

I would prefer a script that incorporates the functionality of postgres-9.5' [`ON CONLFICT DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause, so I don't have to waste time re-uploading observations that are already within the db. I've found the `st_write()` and `st-read()` functions from the `sf` packages to be useful for running SQL queries directly from R, but have hit a roadblock. Currently, I'm stuck trying to upload the 8000 observations within each df from R to my db. I am getting the following error:

### Connecting to database:

```
# db, host, port, pw, and user are all objects in my R environment
con <- dbConnect(drv = RPostgres::Postgres()
             ,dbname = db
             ,host = host
             ,port = port
             ,password = pw
             ,user = user)
```

### Current approach using `RPostgres`:

```
dbWriteTable(con
    ,"table_name" 
    ,df 
    ,append = TRUE
    ,row.names = FALSE)
```

### New approach using `sf`:

```
st_write(conn = conn
      ,obj = df
      ,table = 'table_name'
      ,query = "INSERT INTO table_name ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;"
      ,drop_table = FALSE
      ,try_drop = FALSE
      ,debug = TRUE)
```

### Error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_write") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

### Edit:

Converting to strictly a dataframe, i.e. `df <- as.data.frame(df)` or `attributes(df)$class <- "data.frame"`, resulted in a similar error message, only without the `tbl_df` or `tbl` classes.

### Most recent approach with sf:

I'm making some progress with using `st_write()` by changing to the following:

```
# convert geom from WKT to feature class
df$geom <- st_as_sfc(df$geom)

# convert from data.frame to sf class
df <- st_as_sf(df)

# write sf object to db
st_write(dsn = con # changed from drv to dsn argument
    ,geom_name = "geom"
    ,table = "table_name"
    ,query = "INSERT INTO table_name ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;"
    ,drop_table = FALSE
    ,try_drop = FALSE
    ,debug = TRUE
    )
```

### New Error:

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Failed to fetch row: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist at character 345
```

I'm pretty sure that this is because I have not yet installed the PostGIS extension within my PostgreSQL database. If anyone could confirm I'd appreciate it! Installing PostGIS a pretty lengthy process, so I won't be able to provide an update for a few days. I'm hoping I've solved the problem with the `st_write()` function though!

Comment: Can you try by converting to `data.frame` i.e. `df <- as.data.frame(df)`

Comment: `attributes(df)$class <- "data.frame"`  -might also work

Comment: My `df` is already of class `data.frame`. After paying closer attention to the docs, the `obj` argument must be fed a `sf` class object, not a `data.frame`. I'm away from my desktop at the moment, but I'll try this again soon.

Comment: perhaps try `st_is_valid(df)` to check whether there is a problem with the geometry